ER model Many to Many relationship cannot be correct
I am working on this exercise
In question c) it says that "a prescription clearly identifies the drug" so I assumed that the relationship "identifies" between drug and prescription must be 1 to 1 but if you scroll down to the answer,it says it is many to many and I dont understand why.Since the prescription identifies the drug there can be only one drug/prescription and the text of the prescription says to the pharmacist which drug to use so what is going here?

See, e.g., en.wikipedia on relations.

A Prescription has a many-to-many relationship with Drugs, since a Prescription can have several Drugs (e.g., maybe I have a prescription combining antibiotics and painkillers) and a Drug can appear in several Prescriptions (e.g., the same antibiotic might appear in a prescription for me, and in a prescription for you). In any case, I agree that saying "a prescription clearly identifies the drug" is misleading (I would have preferred a something like "a prescription clearly identifies the drugs...")
